# Emberjs attribute value to handlebar

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have two questions about Handlebars with Ember :

1- I have an input helper which I want to disable or not when clicking a button like this :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
        {{input type="text" class="form-control account-input" value=email placeholder="Email" disabled=isDisabled}}
</div>

App.AccountController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isDisabled: true,

    actions: {
        accountUpdate: function() {
            this.setProperties({isDisabled: false});
        }
    }
});

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" {{action "accountUpdate"}}>Update</button>
```

But the problem is that my input is always enable... am I doing this wrong ?

2- This is most likely the same as the first one. I have a navigation bar in my application template where I put some button such as log out, account etc..
But I wanted to hide it when the user isn't log on my app.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MDF App</a>
            </div>
            {{#if isAuthenticated}}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" {{action "home"}}>Homepage</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" {{action "accountManager"}}>Account</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn navbar-right" {{action "logout"}}>Log out</button>
            {{/if}}
</nav>
```

In my ApplicationController :

```
 App.AuthManager = Ember.Object.extend({
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            Ember.$
                .get(host + '/session', function(data) {
                    console.log('DEBUG: isAuthenticated OK');
                    return true;
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    console.log('DEBUG: isAuthenticated FAIL');
                    return false;
                });
        }
    });

    App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            return App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated();
        }
    });
```

My problem is that my isAuthenticated is not triggered, and I thought I could return a value to my template like that. Should I do it an other way ?

I've put my navbar in the  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make it a computed property, not just a function.

```
isAuthenticated: function() {
    return App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated();
}.property()
```

Note that this won't automatically update when the value of `App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated()` changes. You'll have to trigger the updates yourself.

Comment: You're supposed to put the names of other Ember properties that this property relies on. Your property relies on the value of `App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated()`, but that's not an Ember property that can be watched, so you should leave it blank. I suggest reading the [guide on computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/).

Comment: I have read it but it wasn't really clear to my eyes.. As you said its working fine for the initialization, but how could I send a new value into this template from an other controller ? because just a `this.setProperties({isAuthenticated: true})` isn't enough no ?